# Set buttons in the middle of the body HTML

Tags: html

I have the below html:

```
<BODY>
   Hello:
   <br>
   <button>Hi</button>
   <button>Hey</button>
   <button>Bye</button>
   <hr>
</BODY>
```

I'm trying to make them appear in the centre of the body by placing them inside `<div>` but it didn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you please add sample output which you required

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<BODY>
  Hello:
   <br>
   <div style="text-align:center;">
   <button>Hi</button>
   <button>Hey</button>
   <button>Bye</button>
   </div>
</BODY>
```

If you want it to be centered in the y axis, you can also insert `vertical-align:middle` next to `text-align:center;`.